# SharedPreference in non-activity class

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a class `PreferenceClass` which extends `PreferenceActivity`. The code for this class is as follows:

```
public class Preferenceclass extends PreferenceActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

}}
```

I also have a non activity class `Shakelistener` which implements `SensorListener`. The code for this class is as follows:

```
    public class Shakelistener implements SensorListener {
    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    // Some code
    }}
```

I need to be able to access the preferences from in this non-activity class, but I'm not sure how to do this.

**EDIT**

This is the code I use to access the shared preferences:

```
    String PREF_FILE_NAME = "preferences";

    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myListPreference = pref.getString("listpref", "default choice");
    boolean cb = pref.getBoolean("checkBox", false);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, myListPreference+"-"+cb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This code is giving no errors, but it always evaluates the toast to "default choice-false".

Which PREF_FILE_NAME should I be using in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Take an instance of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) in the constructor of your non-activity class and use that to call all such methods.

Something like this:

```
public class NonActivityClass implements SensorListener{
Context mContext;
public NonActivtiyClass(Context context) {
this.mContext = context;
}
//Rest of your code
}
```

Then do this to create an object of that class in your Activtiy's `onCreate()`:

```
NonActivityClass nac = new NonActivityClass(this);
```

Comment: Raghav SIr can you give me a brief idea how can i do that...
Or it would be  great if you give me some link of any tutorial regarding my problem..

Comment: I am not going to write your app for you. Use the mContext variable to call all the functions you would use in an Activity, in the same way you'd use them there.